# Accessing Elements in PostgreSQL Multidimensional Array Using Result of Subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, multidimensional-array

In PostgreSQL, say I have a table with a column of 2-dimensional array of integers, and another table storing a column of an array of size 2.

```
CREATE TABLE ta (arr int[][]);
CREATE TABLE tb (pos int[]);
```

I want to look up an element in 'arr' based on a value found for 'pos'. I've worked out that I can do it this way:

```
SELECT arr[(SELECT pos[1] FROM tb WHERE ... LIMIT 1)][(SELECT pos[2] FROM tb WHERE ... LIMIT 1)] FROM ta;
```

However, that requires repeating the same subquery twice. Is there a way to achieve this without having to repeat the subquery for every dimension of 'arr'?

(Context: I have a board with x and y coordinates given by 'arr', and need to access a value stored in that board based on the position of a player or object, given by 'pos'. Any suggestions on a better schema for this are also okay, especially if what I'm asking for above isn't possible.)

Comment: Are those the only columns in those tables? How do they relate to each other? Any columns on which can join? If each `arr` has a `pos` why not put them into a single table?

Comment: They're not the only columns, and they have ways to join on each other. I wanted to cut the cruft out of the tables to focus on the array access question.

Comment: Then please post the full table structure, some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: i am researching the same problem, and comments like 'post the full table structure' are not helpful. The problem is clearly stated.